# gnuplot: is it possible to generate result without plotting anything?

Tags: gnuplot

I'd like to use gnuplot canvas to draw a couple of straight lines an analyse their relations. I would like to use "set arrow" function for this.
But gnuplot doesn't generate output until I call plot function.
Is it possible to create a dummy plot with some "markers" only and without plotting anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
set xr [0:1]
set yr [0:1]
unset tics

... arrow code ...

plot NaN notitle
```

which will create a blank plot with your arrows.

Another (more elegant, I think) possibility is to format a data file with columns like this:

```
x y deltax deltay
```

and use a plot command like this:

```
plot 'data.dat' with vectors nohead
```

This method plots one line per row of data.